# passing collection in the route. Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

i want to pass notification in my route but it didn't work,Any help guys?

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              @foreach (auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                <li><a href="{{  url('/verifyservice/'.$notification)}}">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>{{ $notification->data['name'] }} New !! </a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
        </li>
        @endforeach
```

and this is web.php:

```
Route::get('/verifyservice/{notification}','AdminController@verify')->name('verifyservice');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... have you been able to read the docs page for generating URLs (URL Generation), especially for named routes?  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes

Comment: yes but notification is a collection .and i didn' find the right way to pass it @lagbox

Comment: you are not passing the collection, you are iterating the collection and generating a URL using the current notification in the loop

Comment: how canI fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `route` helper to generate a URL to your named route:

```
route('verifyservice', ['notification' => $notification])
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Url Generation - URLs for Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes) `route`

Comment: how can i unserialize the notification in controller because i try the unserialize functions but it didn' work it show me unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 36 bytes

Comment: it isn't serialized ... this should just place the 'id' of the model into the URL so depending on your route handler signature you may have an 'id' or the Model instance do to Route Model Binding